# Derive the approximation for integration using Hermite interpolating polynomial

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

In the question below, the Hermite interpolating polynomial on $a$ and $a+h$ is used to approximate $f(x)$.

From the error, how do i derive it is $O(h^5)$? I need help in understanding the suggested workings below.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Seeing as you are seeking an upper bound on the error, take the absolute value of the expression for the error and use triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\int_a^{a+h} f(x)-H_3(x) dx &= \int_a^{a+h} \frac{f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}(x-a)^2(x-(a+h))^2 dx\\
\Leftrightarrow \left\vert\int_a^{a+h} f(x)-H_3(x) dx\right\vert &= \left\vert\int_a^{a+h} \frac{f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}(x-a)^2(x-(a+h))^2 dx\right\vert\\
&\leq \int_{a}^{a+h}\left\vert\frac{f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}(x-a)^2(x-(a+h))^2\right\vert dx\end{align}

I am sure you can take it from there.